Why minecraft 1.16.5 mod is not being compiled?
I wanted to create my first mod to the minecraft. Which is kind of HACK
has a menu which will be opened when you press the right shift btn. It has these functions: AutoTotem, AutoSprint, Hitbox and GlowESP.
But while compiling I am getting this error:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5/forge-1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5/forge-1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5.jar
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

What to do?
RUSSIAN
Ну, я новичок в этой сфере. Вот я и захотел создать свой первый мод для майнкрафта. Это своего рода ХАК
есть меню, которое открывается при нажатии правой кнопки Shift. Он имеет следующие функции: AutoTotem, AutoSprint, Hitbox и GlowESP. Но при компиляции я получаю эту ошибку:
Не удалось выполнить задачу «:compileJava».
> Не удалось разрешить все файлы конфигурации «:compileClasspath».
    > Не удалось найти net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5.
      Искал в следующих местах:
        - файл:/C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5/forge-1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5.pom
        - файл:/C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5/forge-1.16.5-36.2.42_mapped_official_1.16.5.jar
      Требуется:
          проект :

Возможное решение:
  - Объявить репозиторий, предоставляющий артефакт, см. документацию по адресу https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html.

Что делать?

Help with compiling my minecraft 1.16.5 forge mod

Anybody wanna answer maybe? I really need that guys

Can you show the gradle file ? Also, ask about unallowed things is not allowed on SO. Be carefull and please don't join malicious team
